# How to replace a value that does not exist in an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, inner-join, exists

I need to bring some results from an inner join using only one single table PK(ID, CAR).

```
ID  CAR     VAL    
1   34      A
1   4430    B
1   50      C
2   34      D
2   55      M
```

This is what I have:

```
SELECT A.*, B.CAR, B.VAL    
FROM PRUEBA2 A INNER JOIN PRUEBA2 B ON 
A.ID = B.ID
WHERE 
A.VAL IN ('A','B') AND
A.CAR = 34 AND
B.CAR = 4430
```

But I'm getting this:

```
ID  CAR VAL CAR    VAL
1   34  A   4430   B
```

I need to control two different CAR values. If A.CAR = 34 and A.VAL IN ('A','B'), then if this is true I need to check  what is the VAL of the CAR 4430

I trying to get this as a final result

```
A.ID    A.CAR   A.VAL   B.CAR     B.VAL
1       34      A       4430      B
2       34      D       NP        NP
```

NP = Not Present

How can I reach this? I mean, getting as a result only the data of these two values.

Comment: then remove `b.car=4430`. you can't have it both ways: "show me B where it's ONLY 4430, but also show me all the other B's"

Comment: But in that case I'l have ALL the other CAR values, but I ONLY need these 2

Comment: so `where b.car in (4430, 'NP')`

Comment: OK, NP is used to indicate that the CAR 4430 and its VAL is NOT PRESENT, to be aware of this situation. It's a value that I write somehow in the final result.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT A.*, B.CAR, B.VAL    
FROM PRUEBA2 A LEFT JOIN
     PRUEBA2 B
     ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.CAR = 4430
WHERE A.VAL IN ('A','B') AND
      A.CAR = 34;
```

You can use `COALESCE()` if you don't like the `NULL` value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if this is what you want in all cases but this would give you the output you want for those inputs:

```
SELECT A.*, B.CAR, B.VAL    
FROM PRUEBA2 A 
LEFT JOIN PRUEBA2 B 
    ON A.ID = B.ID AND
       B.CAR = 4430
WHERE A.CAR = 34
```

Note that you can't have `WHERE A.VAL IN ('A','B')` or that would eliminate the `D` row.